# Chain one group of jobs to another group of jobs

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have a long running Windows Service with several one-time jobs (no interval on them). There is one group for establishing connections and one group for setting up listeners.

I want to first establish all connections (can be run concurrently) and after all connections are successful, then I want to start the listener group of jobs.

So in short, I want to chain one group (when all successful) to another group. Jobs in a group can run concurrently.

I've read that triggering groups is not possible but is there any other easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several ways to do this.  One way is to setup a job listener that listens to the group of jobs.  Once all the jobs have finished, the listener can schedule or fire the next group of jobs.

[Tutorial to create your own listener](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html)

```
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(myJobListener,
OrMatcher<JobKey>.Or(GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("myJobGroup"), GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("yourGroup")));
```

Another option is to create a job that runs every minute (or whatever) and checks on the status of things.  Once it sees that all the necessary connections are available, it can fire the next batch of jobs, etc.